# best way of searching a list of files suign core data

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I currently hace a core data project where I'm handling a list of file with some customs meta data, this list can be huge, so I'm trying figure it out what will be the best way to search for properties (meta data) with core data, to be honest what I want to know is if core data is already optimized to handle quick search or I need to create some sort of algorything like a binary tree, what will be best way to do this, I just need some guidance, thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes if you create a core Data model with indexed properties then searches will be fast. However this does not take into consideration the overhead associated with loading and maintaining the list in core data